# how to get notification of devices in the bluetooth range in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, bluetooth

I am working on one application where i need to display notification for the devices in the bluetooth range. I surfed a lot also searched in the stack overflow,but got most of the questions unanswered or the solution to use pacifist,which is quite impossible for me,as i cant download old version of xcode,its not allowed in my organization.

So can anybody help me out with some sort of example code or something that i can use in my application and proceed further?

Thanking you.

-Sarah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this for the Mac or for iOS? If it's the latter, I'm sorry to report that after having researched the heck out of it, there's no App-Store-safe way to access the Bluetooth stack. That leaves no way to detect nearby devices except through Gamekit, which is very limited.

[Edit: note that this is old information, and that much more is available now.]

Comment: basically,i am preparing one iphone application,where i need to show push notification of the other users who are within bluetooth range and for that i need to use bluetooth class.So can you guide me whether i can implement that with the help of Gamekit,and if yes,what are the ways to implement this?

Comment: Gamekit connections are pretty simple, and simplistic: your app looks for connections, telling nearby devices that it wants to be the server, wants to be a client, or is willing to be either. If someone else within range is also running your app and it makes a similar announcement, the two devices will begin to connect. At that point both users acknowledge that they'd like to connect, and they become connected. Each device can connect to up to 3 (or 4?) others. Here's a pretty good tutorial (you have to register, but it's free): http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43502

Comment: Thank you Matthew for your help, i surfed that link,but it has a button event using that only it would start finding the nearby devices,but what i want is like this : the user will get notification of the user withing range who is running the same application. so for the button event will not work. Is there any other way around?

Comment: No, not that I am aware of, sorry. I understand what you want, but lack of access to the Bluetooth stack (or any Bluetooth internals) makes such apps impossible, as near as I can tell.

Comment: ok,no problem,anyways thank you for sparing your precious time.

Comment: Not true any more. Bluetooth-LTE is available in iPhone4s and above, and Bluetooth-over-Zeroconf is available in iOS 4 onwards (it's a limited form of BT, requires you to register a service on both devices, but if your app is running on both, it can work). But Zeroconf/Bonjour is great, but poorly documented by Apple, and painful to work with.

Comment: It's incredibly exciting, really amazing Bluetooth LE stuff going now, including iBeacons.

Answer (score 1):

Try Bonjour for zero-configuration networking/detection between devices. It silently switches between Bluetooth and WiFi but it may still suit your needs.